# ¿Qué tipo de constructor tengo que implementar en este caso?

Tags: c++, constructor

si tengo mi clase `Fecha` con un constructor parecido a este:

```
Fecha::Fecha (int d, int m,int a): dia_(d),mes_(m), anno_(a)
{
  //...
}
```

Y necesito crear una fecha a partir de otra, por ejemplo:

```
Fecha mifecha(mifecha2);
```

y

```
Fecha mifecha = otrafecha;
```

Para hacer eso, ¿qué tipo de constructores necesitaría?
¿Quizás un constructor de copia para el segundo caso, pero y para el primero?

Comment: Puedes copiar toda la estructura de una clase con solo hacer `a = b`, de otra forma si quieres hacer una transformación de otra clase a una diferente, necesitarás hacer una sobrecarga...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Fecha mifecha = otrafecha;
> ```
>
> Para hacer eso, ¿qué tipo de constructores necesitaría?

Necesitas el constructor de copia. Pero si te refirieras a "*¿Qué constructor necesito redactar?*" la respuesta sería: Ninguno.

#### Las funciones especiales.

Hay algunas funciones de objeto que C++ trata de manera especial, éstas son:

1. Constructor por defecto:

   - `Fecha::Fecha()`.
2. Constructor de copia/movimiento:

   - `Fecha::Fecha(const Fecha &)`.
   - `Fecha::Fecha(const Fecha &&)`.
3. Destructor:

   - `Fecha::~Fecha()`.
4. Operador de copia/movimiento-asignación:

   - `Fecha &Fecha::operator =(const Fecha &)`.
   - `Fecha &Fecha::operator =(const Fecha &&)`.

El trato especial que reciben es que si el programador no las redacta, el compilador las redactará de manera automática. Por lo tanto, suponiendo que tu clase `Fecha` tiene este aspecto:

```
struct Fecha
{
    Fecha(int d, int m,int a): dia_(d),mes_(m), anno_(a) {}
private:
    int dia_{}, mes_{}, anno_{};
};
```

Puedes hacer esto sin escribir código adicional:

```
Fecha mifecha(0,0,0);      // Constructor.
Fecha mifecha1(mifecha);   // Constructor de copia (no redactado!).
Fecha mifecha2 = mifecha1; // Constructor de copia (no redactado!).
```

Fíjate que tanto `mifecha1(mifecha)` como `mifecha2 = mifecha1` usan el constructor de copia.

#### Control de las funciones especiales.

En ocasiones es necesario controlar el trabajo que el compilador hace "*a escondidas*", ya sea para que el programador muestre la intencionalidad de su código como para evitar que se generen éstas funciones; para ello se pueden declarar las funciones especiales como `default` o `delete`:

```
struct Fecha
{
    Fecha() = default;
    Fecha &operator =(const Fecha &) = delete;
    Fecha(int d, int m,int a): dia_(d),mes_(m), anno_(a) {}
private:
    int dia_{}, mes_{}, anno_{};
};
```

Cuando se marca una de las funciones especiales como `default` se indica que se delega en el compilador la responsabilidad de redactar esa función, si se marca como `delete` se le prohíbe al compilador generar dicha función; así que con el código anterior se permite que `Fecha` sea construido por defecto pero se prohíbe copiarlo con el operador de copia-asignación.

#### Volviendo a la pregunta:

> ¿Qué tipo de constructores necesitaría?

Ésto sería suficiente:

```
struct Fecha
{
    // Constructor de copia, explícitamente redactado por el compilador
    Fecha(const Fecha&) = default;
    Fecha(int d, int m,int a): dia_(d),mes_(m), anno_(a) {}
private:
    int dia_{}, mes_{}, anno_{};
};
```

Answer (score 3):

> ¿qué tipo de constructores necesitaría?

En ambos casos se usa el constructor copia:

```
Fecha(const Fecha&)
```

¿Y por qué en ambos casos se llama al mismo constructor?

En ambos casos estás creando una copia de un objeto ya existente y esa funcionalidad está soportada única y exclusivamente por el constructor copia. Otro caso diferente sería que el ambos objetos ya existiesen, en ese caso se llamaría al operador de asignación:

```
Fecha& operator=(Fecha const&);
```

Es decir:

```
Fecha f1(2,4,2018)
Fecha f2(f1);         // Constructor copia
Fecha f3 = Fecha(f1); // Constructor copia
Fecha f4 = f1;        // Constructor copia
f4 = f2;              // operador de asignacion
```

Por cierto, nota que, por defecto, el constructor copia y el operador de asignación reciben una implementación por defecto... por eso el programa compila sin necesidad de implementarlos. Salvo que en dichas operaciones necesites realizar operaciones especiales es preferible dejar esa implementación por defecto... como norma general el compilador sabrá gestionar esas funciones mucho mejor que nosotros.

Answer (score 2):

Para entender cuando necesitas un constructor copia, un operador de asignación, y un destructor, vamos a ver primero cuando se invocan.

Cuando haces esto invocas al constructor copia:

```
Fecha miFecha(miFecha2)
```

Y cuando haces esto también:

```
Fecha miFecha = miFecha2;
```

Ambas invocan al constructor copia que sería:

```
Fecha(const Fecha & b);
```

La función de asignación se invoca en asignación, y no en la declaración que es la que va precedida por el tipo de dato.

```
Fecha a(10,12,1994); // inicialización
Fecha b = a; // inicializacion
Fecha c = "10/12/1994"; // inicialización
Fecha d(a); // inicialización
```

Ahora vamos a ver cuando es que los necesitas. Normalmente no necesitas definir estas funciones especiales ya que C++ lo hace por ti. C++ define un operador de asignación por defecto, un constructor copia por defecto, y un destructor por defecto. Adicionalmente C++11 también te regala un constructor copia move por defecto y un operador de asignación move por defecto.

Así que por tu comodidad y para tener que escribir menos código y por lo tanto para tener menos margenes de error no necesitas definir ninguno. Ademas un compilador normalmente siempre sabra definir mejor que tu estas funciones.

Otra cosa es que tu clase utilice punteros. En ese caso prepárate porque toca definir todas estas funciones. Y si los constructores adjudican memoria el destructor debería liberarla.

Por eso con punteros y memoria dinámica el constructor copia y el operador de asignación por defecto no te valen 
ya que meramente realizan una copia superficial o copia miembro a miembro, por lo tanto en una asignación o inicialización a otro objeto lo que consigues es que ambos objetos sostengan punteros a la misma ubicación en memoria y traten de usar delete dos veces ahí. Lo cual termina siendo un desastre, tu programa aborta y todo se va al garete.

Así que tanto si decides que los c.copia y o.asignación hagan una copia profunda o decidas que lleven una cuenta con variables estáticas para liberar esa memoria una sola vez, toca redefinir las 5 funciones especiales. Aun asi sigue siendo posible evitar definir explícitamente estas funciones si por ejemplo usas punteros inteligentes los cuales gestionan su propia memoria.

Más adelante si utilizas bibliotecas es probable que te encuentres con que no quieres que tus punteros inteligentes gestionen memoria usando new y delete. Por ejemplo en SDL2 tenemos punteros que gestionan texturas cargandolas con IMG_LoadTexture y SDL_DestroyTexture. Aquí tienes una referencia para ello:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27331315/typedef-a-shared-ptr-type-with-a-static-custom-deleter-similar-to-unique-ptr

Un saludo.

Comment: Vale @eferion tenia entendido que era asi lo de los constructores en algunos compiladores por lo que he estudiado hasta ahora, edito la respuesta. Ah si, lo del ccopia con valor de retorno es que simplemente me he equivocado escribiendo. Un saludo y gracias por la aclaracion.

Comment: Vale eferion yo ya te habia entendido. Ya lo he corregido. Cuidate compañero.