# ¿Que ocurre cuando usamos el constructor de conversión?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor

el ejemplo será la siguiente clase:

> CLASE PERSONA

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class Persona
{
public:
  Persona(int dnii = 00000000, int edadd = 00) : dni(dnii), edad(edadd) {}
  void mostrarPersona() const;
private:
  int dni;
  int edad;
};

void Persona::mostrarPersona() const
{
  cout << "Su dni es: " << dni << endl;
  cout << "Su edad es: " << edad << endl;
}
```

> MAIN

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Persona.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  //Ejemplos constructor de conversión
  //Conversión de tipo int a tipo Persona
1  Persona p1 = 12345678;
2  Persona p2 = Persona(32011111);
3  Persona p3(33333333);
4  //Persona p4{44444444}; //DA ERROR
5  p1.mostrarPersona();
6  p2.mostrarPersona();
7  p3.mostrarPersona();
8  //p4.mostrarPersona();

  //Conversión de tipo int a tipo Persona en asignaciones

9  p1 = -11111111; //Conversión implícita
10 p2 = Persona(-22222222);
11 //p3 = Persona{33333333}; //ERROR
12  p1.mostrarPersona();
13  p2.mostrarPersona();
14  //p3.mostrarPersona();
}
```

Veamos las dudas que se me presentan:

**Línea 1**

```
Persona p1 = 12345678;
```

Creo el objeto `Persona p1` pero llamando al constructor de conversión. Es decir, llamará al constructor de conversión con pasándole el primer parámetro al constructor, este creará un objeto de tipo entero a tipo Persona.
Aquí llamará al constructor de conversión pero si yo no he definido ninguno, es decir, realiza conversión implícita, ¿qué constructor usa exactamente? El constructor normal y le pasa como primer parámetro ese o es que el compilador ha creado uno de conversión que no se ve/no está definido?

**Línea 2**

```
Persona p2 = Persona(32011111);
```

En este caso me surge la duda siguiente, `Persona(32011111)` va a usar conversión porque recibo un parámetro entero en lugar de un objeto, hasta ahí de acuerdo, pero nuevamente, ¿qué está usando el constructor que he definido y le pasa primer parámetro y el segundo lo inicializa a 0 convirtiéndolo en un objeto p2? ¿Y luego con el = le asigna ese objeto temporal por copia a `Persona p2`? ¿Así es?

**Línea 3**

```
Persona p3(33333333);
```

Estoy creando un objeto `p3` que recibe un parámetro entero, de nuevo, ¿uso el constructor que he definido y le asigna al segundo parámetro un 0 o está usando uno propio de conversión que el compilador ha creado automáticamente?

**Línea 4**

```
//Persona p4{44444444};
```

En teoría la sintaxis de inicialización en C++11 es compatible con `{}` Pero en mi compilador, me da error en esa línea, cuando si no me equivoco, ¿debería de funcionar bien no?

**Líneas 9 10 11**

```
9  p1 = -11111111; //Conversión implícita
10 p2 = Persona(-22222222);
11 //p3 = Persona{33333333}; //ERROR
```

¿Qué hace exactamente aquí? Está construyendo con conversión y luego usa el `operator=()` implícito(creado por el compilador) para asignarlo a un objeto creado?

¿Porqué de nuevo me falla la inicialización con `{}`?

Disculpad mis dudas, pero me ayudáis mucho en la resolución de ellas, un saludo y muchísimas gracias.

Comment: ¿ Como estás llamando al compilador ? Porque tu código es correcto O_O

Comment: Imagino que te refieres por la sintaxis { } que no me funcionan, pues g++ main.cpp  @Trauma

Comment: ¿ Versión del `g++` ? En `g++ 7.2.0` funciona perfecto. Intenta con `g++ -std=c++11`.

Answer (score 1):

**Línea 1**

> ¿qué constructor usa exactamente? El constructor normal y le pasa como primer parámetro ese o es que el compilador ha creado uno de conversión que no se ve/no está definido?

Los constructores pueden ser llamados de forma implícita salvo que los etiquetes con `explicit`:

```
struct A
{
  A(int){ }
};

struct B
{
  explicit B(int){ }
};

int main()
{
  A a = 5; // ok
  B b = 5; // error
}
```

En tu ejemplo se está llamando al constructor `Persona(int,int)`. Si no te lo crees puedes probar a usar `explicit` o a quitar los valores por defecto.

El compilador solo es capaz de crear la implementación de los siguientes elementos:

- Constructor por defecto (sin argumentos)
- Constructor copia
- Constructor *move* (C++11 en adelante)
- Destructor
- Operador de asignación (tradicional y *move*)

Eso sí, hay situaciones bajo las cuales estas funciones no reciben una implementación por defecto por parte del compilador, pero detallarlas casi daría para una respuesta nueva. Lo que está claro es que bajo ningún concepto el compilador va a crear una implementación para `Persona(int)` porque... ¿a qué variable miembro le asigna ese valor y por qué? el compilador no es nadie para tomar esa clase de decisiones por tí.

**Línea 2**

> ¿qué está usando el constructor que he definido y le pasa primer parámetro y el segundo lo inicializa a 0 convirtiéndolo en un objeto p2? ¿Y luego con el = le asigna ese objeto temporal por copia a Persona p2? ¿Así es?

Está sucediendo lo siguiente:

1. Se crea un objeto temporal `Persona(32011111)`
2. Se invoca al constructor copia para inicializar `p2`
3. Se destruye el objeto temporal

**Línea 3**

> ¿uso el constructor que he definido y le asigna al segundo parámetro un 0 o está usando uno propio de conversión que el compilador ha creado automáticamente?

Como ya hemos visto no hay constructor oculto. Se llama al constructor que has definido.

**Línea 4**

> En teoría la sintaxis de inicialización en C++11 es compatible con {} Pero en mi compilador, me da error en esa línea, cuando si no me equivoco, ¿debería de funcionar bien no?

Sí, debería funcionar.

**Líneas 9 10 11**

> ¿Qué hace exactamente aquí? Está construyendo con conversión y luego usa el operator=() implícito(creado por el compilador) para asignarlo a un objeto creado?

Exacto. El caso es similar al presentado para la *línea 2*. Puedes evitar la creación de un objeto temporal implementando un operador de asignación:

```
Persona& operator=(int)
```

> ¿Porqué de nuevo me falla la inicialización con {}?

Lo más probable es que no esté habilitada la compatiblidad con C++11... verifica los flags de compilación.

Answer (score 1):

En C++ cualquier objeto que tenga un constructor que pueda ser llamado con un sólo parámetro, provocará que el parámetro de ese tipo pueda ser convertido implícitamente a tu objeto.

Tu objeto `Persona` puede ser construido con ninguno, uno o dos parámetros:

```
Persona(int dnii = 00000000, int edadd = 00)
```

Dado que puede ser construido con un entero (`int`), es posible convertir `int` en `Persona` recibiendo como segundo parámetro un `0` por defecto, así que en estos casos se está llamando al constructor de un sólo parámetro (conversión `int` a `Persona`) siendo el segundo parámetro `0` por defecto:

```
Persona p1 = 12345678;
Persona p3(33333333);
```

En este otro caso se está llamando al constructor de copia, que ha sido automáticamente generado por el compilador [tal y como ya comentamos en este hilo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/152462/2742):

```
Persona p2 = Persona(32011111);
```

En cuanto a la inicialización con llaves (`{}`), es conocida como "[*Inicialización de agregado*](https://vitaminacpp.wordpress.com/2014/11/04/inicializadores-de-miembros-en-agregados/)" y tiene ciertas restricciones; pero en tu caso `Persona` no es un agregado y por ello no sigue esas restricciones... sin embargo sigue las normas de la "*Inicialización uniforme*" y la "[*Inicialización mediante lista*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/list_initialization)", ambas son características de C++11 o superior y si no estás compilando con un compilador con soporte a C++11 (o superior) no te funcionará.

---

Una nota adicional...

Los literales numéricos que empiezan por `0` son números en base octal, en tu código no pasa nada porque no usas números mayores a `7` en tus literales, pero si tu constructor hubiese sido:

```
Persona(int dnii = 09876543, int edadd = 00)
```

Habrías recibido un error de compilación.

Comment: entonces cuando hacemos     Persona p2 = Persona(32011111);
En este caso por ejemplo, en realidad antes de llamar al constructor de copia llama primero al constructor de conversión y luego ya al de copia, o el de copia ya hace esa conversión de entero a Persona para luego asignarlo a p2?