# explicit en constructores de conversión

Tags: c++

con explicit le digo al constructor que no quiero que me haga conversión, es decir, que o recibe los parámetros exacto que tiene que recibir del mismo tipo o dará error de compilación.

Entonces dada la siguiente clase:

```
class Persona
{
public:
  explicit Persona(int dnii = 00000000, int edadd = 00) : dni(dnii), edad(edadd) {}
  void mostrarPersona() const;
private:
  int dni;
  int edad;
};
```

Yo **no puedo hacer** lo siguiente:

```
Persona p1 = 99999999; //Porque aquí convierto un entero a Persona

p1 = 11111111;  //Porque aquí estoy asignando un entero a un tipo Persona
```

Pero en cambio, **sí que puedo hacer** esto:

```
Persona p1 = Persona(12345678);
Persona p2(1234568);
```

Mi pregunta es, **¿porqué sí puedo hacer esas últimas instrucciones anteriores?**

Si no me equivoco, esto me convierte un entero en Persona con un objeto temporal para luego efectuar su copia en p1:

```
Persona p1 = Persona(12345678);
```

En este caso estoy llamando al constructor de conversión que me hará la conversión de entero a persona, cosa que con explicit le he dicho que no lo haga:

```
Persona p2(1234568);
```

Comment: ¿no será que se te ha olvidado poner `explicit` en el código?

Comment: Exacto @eferion qué cabeza! Pero aun así, desde donde estoy estudiando dice que sí podría hacer las instrucciones las instrucciones que comento.

Comment: no es cierto... te han dicho que si se pueden hacer las llamadas explícitas... las otras no. La respuesta de @JYass se basaba en el hecho de que `explicit` no estaba puesto

Comment: Ya ya, te he entendido @eferion, quiero ser más explícito, me refiero que desde donde estudio, me pone que las instrucciones del enunciado no puedo hacer + las instrucciones que os pongo y sí puedo hacer + instrucciones que os expongo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En el ejemplo propuesto:

```
class Persona
{
public:
  Persona(int dnii = 00000000, int edadd = 00) : dni(dnii), edad(edadd) {}
  void mostrarPersona() const;
private:
  int dni;
  int edad;
};
```

Si te permiten las siguientes instrucciones:

```
Persona p1 = 99999999;
Persona per3 = { 99999999, 25 };
```

Porque al compilador le está permitido  resolver los párametros del constructor y convertir implicitamente el valor entero 99999999 a un objeto de tipo `Persona` con el parámetro `dni` con valor 99999999 en el primer caso, y en el segundo convierte implícitamente a un objeto de tipo `Persona` con `dni` 99999999 y `eddad` 25.

Si añadimos el especificador [explicit](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit):

```
class Persona
    {
    public:
      explicit Persona(int dnii = 00000000, int edadd = 00) : dni(dnii), edad(edadd) {}
      void mostrarPersona() const;
    private:
      int dni;
      int edad;
    };
```

No te permiten las instrucciones anteriores porque no se permite la conversión implicita ni la inicialización por copia. Sin embargo:

```
Persona p1 = Persona(12345678);
Persona p2(1234568);
```

Si son permitidas, porque al objeto `p1` de tipo `Persona` le estas asignando un valor de tipo `Persona`, con el parámetro `dni` 1234568 y parámetro `edadd` 0.

El objeto `Persona(12345678)` **no es un `int` convertido a `Persona`**, es un **objeto `Persona` con un parámetro dni de tipo `int`** con valor 1234568 .

En la segunda instrucción, hay una inicialización directa al objeto `p2` de tipo `Persona` para el parámetro `dni` con el valor 12345678 , pero en ninguno de los dos casos se está realizando una conversión implicita entre un `int` y `Persona` , sino que le estás asignando directamente el valor al parámetro dni.

Answer (score 5):

El especificador `explicit` marca a un constructor (o desde C++11 también los operadores de conversión) para que no acepte en sus parámetros conversiones implícitas o inicializaciones por copia.

#### Conversiones implícitas.

C++ permite convertir algunos tipos entre si de manera automática y transparente, estas conversiones se conocen como conversiones implícitas y están descritas en el apartado 7 del [estándar de C++](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4659.pdf) (traducción y resaltado míos):

> #### 7. Conversiones estándar
>
> 1. **Las conversiones estándar son conversiones implícitas** con significado fundamental para el lenguaje. [...]
> 2. [...]
> 3. **Una expresión `e` puede ser *implícitamente convertida* a un tipo `T` si y sólo si la declaración `T t=e;` es correcta, para una imaginaria variable temporal `t`**.
> 4. [...]
> 5. Algunos constructos del lenguaje requieren la conversión a un valor que tenga un conjunto de tipos apropiados para dicho constructo. **Una expresión `e` de tipo `E` que aparezca en dicho contexto se considerará *contextualmente implícitamente convertida* al tipo `T` especificado y es correcta si y sólo si puede ser implícitamente convertida al tipo `T`** de la siguiente manera: Se buscan funciones de conversión a `E` no explícitas cuyo tipo de retorno sea `cv T` o referencia a `cv T` de manera que `T` sea permitida en ese contexto. Debe haber exactamente una de esas `T`.
> 6. **El efecto de cualquier conversión implícita es el mismo que realizando la correspondiente declaración e inicialización para a continuación usar la variable temporal como resultado de la conversión**. [...]

Lo que viene a decir el estándar es que un tipo `A` podrá ser convertido implícitamente a `B` si el siguiente código es correcto:

```
A a;
B b = a;
```

Como ya hemos visto en [otra pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/154058/que-ocurre-cuando-usamos-el-constructor-de-conversi%C3%B3n), el código anterior será correcto si el tipo `B` tiene un constructor que reciba `A` como parámetro.

#### `int` implícitamente convertible a `Persona`.

Usemos tu clase `Persona` como ejemplo:

```
Persona::Persona(int dnii = 00000000, int edadd = 00) :
    dni(dnii), edad(edadd) {}
```

En el punto 7.6 del estándar nos indica que este código...

```
Persona temporal(1);   // Construir Persona usando '1' (int) como parámetro
Persona p1 = temporal; // Usar temporal para construir p1 mediante copia de temporal.
```

... es equivalente a este...

```
// Construye un Persona temporal con parámetro '1' (int) ...
// ... y lo usa para construir p1 mediante la copia del temporal.
Persona p1 = 1;
```

... y que esto es una conversión implícita. Si marcas el constructor de `Persona` como `explicit` prohibirás las conversiones implícitas:

```
class Persona
{
public:
  explicit Persona(int dnii = 00000000, int edadd = 00) :
    dni(dnii), edad(edadd) {}
  void mostrarPersona() const;
private:
  int dni;
  int edad;
};

Persona p1 = 1;          // Incorrecto, conversión implícita.
Persona p2 = Persona{1}; // Correcto, sin conversiones (constructor de copia por defecto).
```

En el caso de `p2` no se realiza ninguna conversión, se llama al constructor de copia definido automáticamente por el compilador (cómo ya se explicó en [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151643/qu%C3%A9-tipo-de-constructor-tengo-que-implementar-en-este-caso)).

> ```
> Persona p1 = Persona(12345678);
> Persona p2(1234568);
> ```
>
> Mi pregunta es, **¿porqué sí puedo hacer esas últimas instrucciones anteriores?**

Porque estás invocando al constructor de copia (automáticamente generado por el compilador) de `Persona`.